# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'mountComponent' of undefined error when running create-react-app build version

Tags: reactjs, webpack, react-router, react-redux, create-react-app

#### Steps to Reproduce

My create-react-app works fine on development mode, but it is blank page when I run the built one using (npm run build) with this console error.

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'mountComponent' of undefined
    at r (patchUtils.js:51)
    at e.exports (reactPatches.js:41)
    at react.js:59
    at Object.ready (reactInternals.js:24)
    at r (react.js:58)
    at Object.<anonymous> (index.js:12)
    at t (bootstrap 3c1adc8fa04e423f7356:19)
    at Object.<anonymous> (main.448e9d91.js:66458)
    at t (bootstrap 3c1adc8fa04e423f7356:19)
    at bootstrap 3c1adc8fa04e423f7356:62
    at bootstrap 3c1adc8fa04e423f7356:62
```

I didn't change any create-react-app config. One thing I'm suspecting is this part of code and the structure.

```
class SocialIntegrator extends React.Component {
  static propTypes = { children: PropTypes.node.isRequired };

  componentDidMount = () => {
    if (!initialized) {
      initialized = true;

      installFacebookSdk();
      installPinterest();
      installTwitter();
    }
  };

  render = () => React.Children.only(this.props.children);
}

export default SocialIntegrator;
```

Here's App.js .

```
import React from "react";
import { Provider } from "react-redux";
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Switch } from "react-router-dom";
import PageLayoutRoute from "components/controls/PageLayoutRoute";
import { SocialIntegrator } from "components/Social";
import { createStore } from "store";
import routes from "components/routes";
import HomePage from "components/HomePage";
import StudioPage from "components/StudioPage";
import FramingPage from "components/FramingPage";
import OrderReviewPage from "components/OrderReviewPage";
import OrderConfirmationPage from "components/OrderConfirmationPage";
import { injectGlobal } from "styled-components";
injectGlobal`
  html {
    overflow-y: auto;
  }
`;
const store = createStore();

const App = () =>
  <SocialIntegrator>
    <Provider store={store}>
      <Router>
        <Switch>
          <PageLayoutRoute exact path={routes.home} component={HomePage} />
          <PageLayoutRoute path={routes.studio} component={StudioPage} />
          <PageLayoutRoute path={routes.framing} component={FramingPage} />
          {/* */}
          <PageLayoutRoute path="/checkout" component={OrderReviewPage} />
          <PageLayoutRoute path="/orderConfirmed" component={OrderConfirmationPage} />
        </Switch>
      </Router>
    </Provider>
  </SocialIntegrator>;

export default App;
```

Here's createStore.js.

```
import { createOpbeatMiddleware } from "opbeat-react/redux";
import { applyMiddleware, createStore } from "redux";
import thunk from "redux-thunk";
import reducer from "./reducer";

export default () =>
  createStore(
    reducer,
    window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__ &&
      window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__(),
    applyMiddleware(thunk, createOpbeatMiddleware())
  );
```

#### Export/Import

So I'm using subfolders with `index.js` in each of them to export each component.
export: Social/index.js

```
export { default as SocialIntegrator } from "./controls/SocialIntegrator";
```

import: index.js

```
import { SocialIntegrator } from "components/Social";
```

#### Environment

1. `node -v`:  v8.4.0
2. `npm -v`: v4.6.1
3. `yarn --version` (if you use Yarn): 0.20.0
4. `npm ls react-scripts` (if you haven’t ejected): v1.0.14

Comment: How are you rendering the app?  Something like this?  Are you targeting a valid DOM element?

`React.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));`

Comment: yeah. `ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));`

Comment: Just reproduced the issue. It's pretty similar. Sorry it took quite a bit of time.
https://github.com/Seunghunsh/create-react-app-react-dev-tools-issue-minimal-reproduce

Answer (score 2):

Please see my explanation here: Uncaught TypeError: [Cannot read property 'mountComponent' of undefined error when running create-react-app build version](https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app/issues/3335#issuecomment-341677369)

You are using a library that depends on private React APIs. Those APIs don't exist anymore. (And were never meant to be used directly.)

Comment: Thank you so much! For people who see this article, it was caused from 'opbeat' app that only supports react 15, while I was using react 16.